# Why I got 403 forbidden with nginx in docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I try to set up ssl with Let’s Encrypt using this article https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71

my nginx config

```
server {
    listen       80;

    server_name kcr.ttfr.ru;
    server_name  www.kcr.ttfr.ru;

    root /var/www/k4fntr/public;
    index /frontend/index.html;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    gzip on; # enable gzip
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    location / {
         try_files /frontend/$uri $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # permalinks
         client_max_body_size 128M;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
            deny all; # deny hidden files
    }

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
            deny all; # deny scripts
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            expires max; # cache static files
            try_files /frontend/$uri $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # permalinks
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_pass   k4fntr_php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://k4fntr_echo:6001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/kcr.ttfr.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/kcr.ttfr.ru/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { root /var/www/certbot; }
}
```

but my challenges were failed because of url /.well-known/acme-challenge/ returns 403:Forbidden

what's wrong with my nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

change your location to something like this:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
      root /var/www/certbot;
      default_type text/plain;
    }
```

another question. Do you want to redirect all non-http traffic to https?
In that case I would create a server block listen port 80 and another one listen on 443.

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    domain.io;

      location / {
        return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
       }

      location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root root /var/www/certbot;
        default_type text/plain;
      }
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    domain.io;
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; 
       ...
}
```